# iPhone landscape not ignoring media query

Tags: ios, media-queries

I have a media query like this...

```
@media all and (min-width:1200px){ ...css in here... }
```

I want ANY screen over 1200 wide to display the styling in that query.

It's working on all screens that I've tested, however, it's also applying that styling to the iPhone 6 model A1586 (not iPhone 6 Plus) when it's in landscape. Why is that, and what query would be required for the iPhone landscape mode to ignore that styling?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Is it an iPhone 6 plus?

Comment: No - it's a 6 - model A1586 (I'll update my question) - thanks Mitchell